# NGINX Serve Precompressed index file without source

Tags: nginx, gzip

I have found an interesting problem.

I am trying to serve some gzipped files without the sources using NGINX's gzip_static module (I know the downsides to this). This means you can have gzipped files on the server that will be served with transfer-encoding: gzip. For example, if there's a file /foo.html.gz, a request for /foo.html will be served the compressed file with content-encoding: text/html.

While this usually works it turns out that when looking for index files in a directory the gzipped versions are not considered.

```
GET /index.html
200

GET /
403
```

I was wondering if anyone knows how to fix this.  I tried setting `index.html.gz` as in index file but it is served as a gzip file rather then a gzip encoded html file.

Comment: Are you looking to send compressed response or pre-compressed static files? They are different - http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_module.html ; http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_static_module.html

Comment: I am trying to serve compressed static files.

Comment: With the “always” value (1.3.6), gzipped file is used in all cases, without checking if the client supports it. It is useful if there are no uncompressed files on the disk anyway or the ngx_http_gunzip_module is used.  So you write: "gzip always", instead of "gzip on"

Answer (score 7):

This clearly won't work this way.

This is a part of the module [source](http://lxr.nginx.org/source/src/http/modules/ngx_http_gzip_static_module.c):

```
 if (r->uri.data[r->uri.len - 1] == '/') {
     return NGX_DECLINED;
 }
```

So if the uri ends in slash, it does not even look for the gzipped version.

But, you probably could hack around using rewrite. 
(This is a guess, I have not tested it)

```
rewrite ^(.*)/$ $1/index.html;
```

Edit: To make it work with autoindex (guess) you can try using this instead of rewrite:

```
location ~ /$ { 
    try_files ${uri}/index.html $uri;
}
```

It probably is better overall than using rewrite. But you need to try ...

Comment: Thanks, this works! Unfortunately, it breaks `autoindex`. Do you think there's a way to make it work with `autoindex`?

Comment: @ReyCharles maybe this one is better. but i haven't tested

Comment: Unfortunately that solution has the same problem.

Comment: Actually, scratch that - You need to put ${uri}/index.html in quotes. It'll *only* show the autoindex.

Comment: The rewrite worked for me.  Since I did not need autoindex that was not a dealbreaker for me.  Thank you Fox.

Answer (score 0):

You can prepare your precompressed files then serve it.
Below it's prepared by PHP and served without checking if the client supports gzip.

```php
// PHP prepare the precompressed gzip file
file_put_contents('/var/www/static/gzip/script-name.js.gz', gzencode($s, 9));
// where $s is the string containing your file to pre-compress
```

```js
// NginX serve the precompressed gzip file
location ~ "^/precompressed/(.+)\.js$" {
    root /var/www;
    expires 262144;
    add_header Content-Encoding gzip;
    default_type application/javascript;
    try_files /static/gzip/$1.js.gz =404;
}
```

```
# Browser request a file - transfert 113,90 Kb (uncompressed size 358,68 Kb)
GET http://inc.ovh/precompressed/script-name.js

# Response from the server
Accept-Ranges bytes
Cache-Control max-age=262144
Connection keep-alive
Content-Encoding gzip
Content-Length 113540
Content-Type application/javascript; charset=utf-8
ETag "63f00fd5-1bb84"
Server NginX
```